# How to add text above a marker on Google Maps in JS?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I found [exactly the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11286258/how-to-add-text-above-a-marker-on-google-maps) for Java, but I'd like to do that in JS. So, how to add text above a marker on Google Maps in JS?

Comment: Inb4 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25934816/add-text-to-google-maps - this question considers adding fixed text as legend, but I'd like to have text above a marker on map.

Comment: Have you checked out [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#marker_labels) section of the MapMarker API?

Comment: @G.Hunt - thanks! That's not ideal answer for my problem, because labels are one-letter only, but I'll consider to follow it in absence of better solutions :)

Comment: They're not 1 letter, I have used this before and you can in fact use multiple letters in the marker label.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I didn't notice that :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As stated in my comment, You can use multiple letters for the map marker label.

If you use the `label` property when instantiating a `new google.maps.Marker` class, you pass it an object, with one of the properties `text`.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
    icon: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png',
    label: { color: '#00aaff', fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: '14px', text: 'Your text here' }
});
```

Check the fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8p8e1vdp/).

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for isn't included in the standard library.  Google do provide this interesting [utility library](https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wikis/Libraries.wiki#MarkerWithLabel) though so you can make your own markers, labels.  The one you want is the MarkerWithLable class. From the link:

> This class behaves like `google.maps.Marker`, but it supports the
>   association  of a label with the marker. If the marker is draggable,
>   so too will be the  label. In addition, a marker with a label responds
>   to all mouse events in  the same manner as a regular marker. It also
>   fires mouse events and  "property changed" events just as a regular
>   marker would.

Looks like it's used in much the same way a the standard Marker class and there appears to be ample examples of it's use kicking around so good luck and I hope that this was helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

I've attached a quick implementation of the [infowindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows). Be sure to replace my API_KEY with yours as I've only allowed access to the stack snippets url.

This code snippet creates an infowindow. In the example, the infowindow is called instantly after being created to display it's content above the marker.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
       #map {
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
       }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>My Google Maps Demo</h3>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      function initMap() {
        var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: uluru
        });
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: 'Welcome to stackoverflow!'
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: uluru,
          map: map
        });
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

To only show the infowindow when the marker is clicked, wrap it inside of a listener:

```
marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
});
```

Comment: No explanation of lables in your example code. Irrelevant to the question.